# iOS - Choose picture from gallery or camera then crop, drag, delete or resize the picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, drawing, scale

I'm working on an drawing project. I need to choose picture from gallery or take a picture from camera. Then user can crop the image. After that user can add the cropped picture to current DrawingView. User can add many pictures as they want. Finally user can click on one of pictures then resize, drag it to another location in current DrawingView or delete it.

I know how to use camera and choose picture from gallery but I don't know how to continue.

This video can express one of features which I said:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0nJ3wJsXqY

Please give me some advices or keywords.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please condense your question to focus on *one* of the many tasks you list that you are trying to accomplish :)

Comment: 1 - I want to add many images from camera or gallery
2 - I want to crop when choose image or take a picture from camera
3 - I want to scale and move for each image